# history.push and state resetting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, functional-programming

Using  props.history.push step forms is messing up my state. I have a mult-step form and keep the current step in the state of the component. In addition, between steps I need to change the URL in the same component, so I have a conditional route working. In between next and previous I am calling a function to update the current step, the current step counter is working like a charm when clicking through the steps. The issue comes when needing to change the URL.

Using props.history.push(route) is re-rendering the component and the current step counter is lost and set back to 0 (its initial value). How can I avoid to loose the counter in the state? The code snippet is the following:

```
const StepForm = (props, state, next, prev,) => [
  {
    title: "Step 1",
    content: <StepOne />,
    buttons: [
      null,
      <Button onClick={() => next_step()}> Next </Button>,
    ],
  },
  {
    title: "Step 2",
    content: (<stepTwo/>),
    buttons: [
      <Button
        onClick={() => {
          next_step(); //Somehow this does not execute in this step. If
          props.history.push( // I remove history.push, the state is kept
            `/items/${item.id}`
          );
        }}
      >
        Next
      </Button>,
    ],
  },
  {
    title: "Step 3",
    content: <StepThree />,
    buttons: [
      null,
      <Button onClick={() => next_step()}> Done </Button>,
    ],
  },
];


export class ItemPage extends Component {
  state = {
    step: 0,
  };
  
  next_step = () => this.setState((prevState) => ({ step: prevState.step + 1 }));
  prev_step = () => this.setState((prevState) => ({ step: prevState.step - 1 }));
  
  render() {
    const Forms = StepForms(
      this.props,
      this.state,
      this.next_step,
      this.prev_step);
    
    <Steps step={this.state.step}>
       {Forms.map((step) => (
         <Steps.Step key={step.title} title={step.title} />
       ))}
    </Steps>
    <Col span={24}>
      <div>{Forms[this.state.step].content}</div>
    </Col>
```

The issue is that component is re-render with props.history.push(), and step variable in state is reset to 0. How should I avoid resetting state?

Thanks

Comment: Hello @John Barton Which Version of react you are using

Comment: Which redux are you using.Redux saga or context api

Comment: React 16.14.0 and Redux.

Comment: I have answered your question.Please let me know if you are having trouble implementing redux persistent.I will try to help you out.Also post your redux store.js file and app.js file so that I can help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using simple redux is that whenever a refresh occurs,all the states are lost.This problem can be easily resolved using [redux-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist).This library was developed to overcome this problem.By using this along with redux.It will make your state saved even when a url changes or a refresh occurs.It basically is a type of local storage in the browser.It is easy to setup.

It basically adds persistReducer and persistStore to your setup.Thats makes the state to be saved even on a refresh.
All you need to do is.
Wrap up your app with persist gate like this in App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import store from './app/store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist';

let persistor = persistStore(store);

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
          <App/>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Then in store.js

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import counterReducer from '../features/counter/counterSlice';

const reducers = combineReducers({
  counter: counterReducer,
});

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  middleware: [thunk],
});

export default store;
```

In this way you can easily add redux persist to save your state permenanyly.This will resolve your problem.Thanks.

Here is a complete detailed article for it.
[Using redux-persist with redux](https://edvins.io/how-to-use-redux-persist-with-redux-toolkit)